# How to find the maximum values in an array?

Tags: c, algorithm

Example

Say that I have an array:

```
Array = (9, 1, 9, 9);
```

how can I loop through the array and print the value and position of each maximum value?

so it will print

```
Value: 9 and Position: 0
Value: 9 and Position: 2
Value: 9 and Position: 3
```

I am having trouble creating an algorithm for it.

Comment: Not a suitable question for this site.

Comment: Why don't you approach it incrementally? First *write some code* that iterates through the list and prints out all the values. Then extend your code to figure out the maximum value. Then extend it again to find and display position and value for those items..

Comment: @BlueFlame How is this not a suitable question?

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer No attempt at solving the problem. "am having trouble" doesn't cut it - we need to see some code / a high-level idea.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer for starters, it shows little to no research effort. This is not a 'do my homework for me' site, it's a 'help me solve this problem that I'm stumped on' site. The user could at least write some code and show he has attempted to do it himself..

Comment: because he didn't even try.

Comment: @Dukeling The way of asking the question might not be suitable, the core question "how do i compute the maximum values" is.

Comment: @JVMATL: +1 for sound advice on how to tackle this problem (and programming problems in general)

Comment: This question is interesting since it is not "just" finding the maximum it is also asking how to print all the indices of the maximal value. A starter-programmer could bang his head trying to do that in one pass, rather than do it in two passes, and later try to optimize the solution to single pass.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer yes, the 'core question' may be suitable - but honestly, is there anybody on this site (other than 1st semester CS students working on their first few projects) who can't solve that core question? Anyway, we're not voting on the 'core question', we're voting on the *actual* question, as written. As written, the question shows zero research effort - if we start to answer questions like that, the quality of the entire site degenerates into 'please do stuff for me so I don't have to think…' The user is free to try it out and post a better question.

Comment: @zenpoy I agree, trying to do it in one pass makes it marginally interesting, but the guidelines for this site say that good questions require effort - where's the code that he tried and doesn't work?

Comment: @BlueFlame This was not a homework assignment and yes I did attempt to do the problem on my own successfully by having an array of pointers to the array of numbers. however, i thought that i was doing too much to solve the problem so thats why I asked the question online for a simpler idea. i didnt fill the need to put my code up because I didnt need help with my code; i needed help finding a simpler algorithm, sometimes i over complicate things.

Comment: +1 for OP. The question is well-posed and the OP's comments have clarified the amount of prior research undertaken. Any trial code would only create question clutter in this particular instance.

Comment: @user3113044 Then you should post the code (/ a high-level description of it / pseudo-code) in the question and ask for a simpler solution. Regardless of whether or not you actually attempted to solve the problem yourself, as it's written, it doesn't look like you did anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to go over the array once and find the max value, then go over the array again and print the message with the current index each time you get to an element which is equal to the max you have found.

Answer (score 2):

1) Iterate through all values in array to find MAX value

2) Iterate again to print position if current value == MAX value

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudo code for one pass algorithm : -

```
list maxs;
int maxvalue = arr[0];

maxs = new list();
maxs.append(0);

for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {

   if(maxvalue<arr[i]) {

       maxvalue = arr[i];
       maxs = new list();
       maxs.append(i);
   }

   else if(maxvalue==arr[i]) {

        maxs.append(i); 
   }

}

print(maxvalue,maxs);
```